# Adding ArrayList of JLabels into JPanel

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm currently experimenting with Java where I've created a JFrame to pop up on the screen when the program is executed.

I have also created an ArrayList of JLabels and a for loop to recursively add JLabels into the array.

Up to this point, I 'think' I've succeeded, but now I want to be able to use this ArrayList to recursively add the elements of the ArrayList into visual JLabels inside my Jframe.

Here is my whole code (It's only small)

```
public class Executable {
     private static JFrame view; 
     private static JLabel image; 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    view = new JFrame("adding labels"); 
    view.setBounds(0,0,300,1000); 
    view.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    view.setVisible(true); 

    ArrayList<JLabel> label = new ArrayList<JLabel>(); 

    for(int i=0; i < 20; i++) { 
        image = new JLabel("Test"); 
        image.setText("image-icon-"+i);
        image.setBounds(0,0,200,200); 
        image.setBackground(Color.green); 
        image.setOpaque(true); 
        label.add(image); 
    }

    JPanel p = new JPanel(); 

    for (JLabel j:label) { 
        p.add(j); 
    } 
    view.add(p); 
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who could offer assistance.

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Comment: Not getting any error messages, I just need to be pointed in the right direction on how to actually add the Labels from the array list visually onto my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a loop that iterates over every JLabel in your arraylist, and adds them to a JPanel (which is then added to JFrame).

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();    
for(JLabel j:label){
    p.add(j);
}
view.add(p);
```

Comment: Tried changing that, doesn't seem to be working. Please see my updated code as i've added everything i've got on my screen up to now. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 4 years late, but I recently ran into a similar issue so this is for those who run into an issue like this. You need to call view.revalidate() and then view.repaint() after adding your JPanel 'p' to the JFrame 'view'. I ran the code with and without the revalidate and repaint and it does end up working when I call those methods.